# How to change tabs within a if statement from a broadcasted variable?

Tags: android, if-statement

Hi fellow coders I really need help and I am really out of ideas, tried a lot of ideas and none worked for me....

I am busy with a **emission survey application** and I am trying to change the tab within the if statement, if the value being **broadcasted** is 1, it go to the second tab and then to the third automatically... Attached is snippets, please help, I would really be grateful....!

The first image is of me sending the data back to the first tab
(All is still working at this moment)

```
    loadB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
            tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
            sendData3();
        }
        private void sendData3() {
            take = "1";
            Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
            dataIntent.setAction("com.example.e3soft.receiver");
            dataIntent.putExtra("taken", take);
            sendBroadcast(dataIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Without the if statement everything works, please help........!

```
private void receiveData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            take = intent.getStringExtra("taken");

        }

    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.example.e3soft.receiver");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    changeTab();
}

protected void changeTab() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), take, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        if (take.equals("1")) {
            populateVariables();
            TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
            tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
            sendData();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your this code inside onReceive :

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.example.e3soft.receiver");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
changeTab();
```

Comment: Thanx for your help, I tried it this morning, all worked now its just super slow lol.... thanx a lot I really appreciate it...